# priority queue with constant time successor operation

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, heap, priority-queue

I'm looking for a linked data structure (because I don't know how many items I'm dealing with at run time) that can be used both as a **priority queue** and as a **linked list**. In other words: searching, inserting and deleting each should not take longer than logarithmic time, but every node should also have a **next**-pointer which should always point to the smallest element that is bigger than itself (at every insert and delete at least one of these have to get updated at each insert and delete, of course).

(I want the pointers so I can for example print a random node and a given number of its immediate successors.)

For me that's a pretty common problem, that shouldn't be that hard to solve even for a novice programmer like me, but I don't know a data structure that can do that:

It seems like I can't use **binary heaps**, because finding the next element is not trivial, unless I convert the whole heap into a list by removing every single item in linear time while loosing the ability to ever insert or delete in log time again.

Searching for every successor key in **balanced search trees** is better than converting the heap, but logarithmic time for each successor still seems to be quiet a waste of cycle for such a trivial task.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :).

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). Insert and find are O(log n) (amortized). Remove first is O(1). Finding the successor is O(1).

You could also create a [threaded search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree), in which case finding the successor is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use balanced search trees. To provide O(1) neighbor access, you can maintain direct neighbor links in logarithmic time during modifying operations which are O(log(n)) anyway.